# Copying packets from an interface to another

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, packet-capture

I have a Linux system (let it be A) with 2 ethernet cards, namely eth0 and eth1 which are attached to two totally unrelated LANs.

Basically eth0 is used for normal application traffic and eth1 is used only for debugging purposes. Debugging means that eth1 is linked using a cross cable to another linux box (let it be B) which runs Wireshark. I want Wireshark to be able to process application packets travelling on A's eth0.

Basically I need to *copy* travelling packets from eth0 interface to interface eth1 so that Wireshark on box B can sniff them (for some reasons I don't have physical access to LAN eth0).
I could also need to specify which packets to copy from eth0 to eth1 according to some rule (based only on TCP/IP fields by the way).

Also note that A's eth0 don't need to be put in promiscuous mode because I only want to copy a subset of packets which have A as destination

Is there a way to achieve this using iptables alone? Or do i need to write an application to make this work? What should I do to "copy" the packets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your kernel is recent enough you could use [iptables --tee](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDU) to forward frames from eth0 to the capture machine.

Comment: That link is now password protected.

Answer (score 6):

You can use tc mirred action. For example:
For incoming traffic:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 ingress
tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: \
   protocol all prio 2 u32 \
   match u32 0 0 flowid 1:1 \
   action mirred egress mirror dev eth1
```

For outgoing traffic:

```
tc qdisc replace dev eth0 parent root handle 10: prio
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 10: \
   protocol all prio 2 u32 \
   match u32 0 0 flowid 10:1 \
   action mirred egress mirror dev eth1
```

Answer (score 3):

Search the net for tcpbridge, which is exactly what does the Job. It can be used to talk to virtual machines as well.

Comment: https://github.com/appneta/tcpreplay

Answer (score 2):

A device that copies ethernet frames from one interface to another is a bridge.  You can configure your Linux system to act as a bridge.  Some documentation can be found here:

- http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge

You can apply filtering rules to bridged traffic using [ebtables](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/), which is an analog of `iptables` for layer 2 traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [rinetd](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/) *might* work (redirector/server for TCP *only* I believe, so no ARP, Layer 2, etc.), but in all honesty, getting some managed switches that have port mirroring capabilities or if that box is solely used for wireshark, you could add another NIC to it, bridge the two interfaces, put it in front of machine A's eth0, and have a dedicated sniffing machine.

Answer (score 0):

In my setup multicast TX traffic was marked by iptables but policy routing using new routing tables never worked. Though it worked for unicast TX packets (redirecting originating packets from eth0 to eth5). Using tc i could get eth0 mcast traffic to eth5 The src mac and src ip address are changed t that of eth5 so will no create issues with switch learnings. All kernel support for kernel packet scheduling CONFIG_NET_SCHED must be enabled

Below WORKS for unicast and multicast traffic redirecting from eth0 to eth5

Netfilter can be used to interact directly with the structure representing a packet in the kernel. This structure, 
the sk_buff, contains a field called “__u32 nfmark” that we are going to modify.
TC will then read that value to select the destination class of a packet.

IP_ADDR_ETH0=`ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr'| cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr -d '\n'`
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -s ${IP_ADDR_ETH0} -p udp --match multiport --dports 329,330 -o eth0 -j MARK --set-mark 2

Going to create a tree that represents our scheduling policy, and that uses the PRIO qdisc (packet scheduler) (can try other available ones).
qdiscs attaching at the root of a device

tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 15: prio

Now have on one side a traffic shaping policy, and on the other side packets marking. To connect the two, we need a filter.

refer man tc-mirred(8):
The mirred action allows packet mirroring (copying) or redirecting
(stealing) the packet it receives. Mirroring is what is sometimes referred to as Switch Port Analyzer (SPAN) and is commonly used to analyze and/or debug flows.

refer man tc-fw(8):
fw - fwmark traffic control filter
the fw filter allows to classify packets based on a previously set fwmark by iptables.  If it is identical to the filter's 'handle', the filter matches. iptables allows to mark single packets with the MARK target, or whole connections using CONNMARK.

MAC_ADDR_ETH1=`cat /sys/class/net/eth1/address`
IP_ADDR_ETH1=`ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr'| cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr -d '\n'`
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 15:0 protocol ip prio 1 handle 0x2 fw action pedit ex munge eth src set ${MAC_ADDR_ETH1} pipe \
action pedit ex munge ip src set ${IP_ADDR_ETH1} pipe \
action mirred egress redirect dev eth1

show above set rules:
tc qdisc show dev eth0
tc filter show dev eth0

delete/unset above set rules:
tc qdisc del dev eth0 root